# How can I change a text in Magento 2 Checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

How can I change text in checkout page in Magento 2?
I already googled but most suggested to change a translation file (.csv) - This is not a ideal solution I think.

Especially, I want to change a text '**Apply Discount Code**'.

When I search the text in all file, I found a file is using the text.
(File path: \vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\coupon.phtml)

```
<div class="fieldset coupon<?= strlen($block->getCouponCode()) ? ' applied' : '' ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="remove" id="remove-coupon" value="0" />
    <div class="field">
        <label for="coupon_code" class="label"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Enter discount code') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCouponCode()) ?>" placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Enter discount code')) ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <?php if (!strlen($block->getCouponCode())): ?>
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action apply primary" type="button" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Apply Discount') ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Apply Discount') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="primary">
                <button  type="button" class="action cancel primary" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Cancel Coupon') ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Cancel Coupon') ?></span></button>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Help! Thank you in advance...

Comment: You aren't want override core html ?

Comment: No but I used purchased theme.

Answer (score 0):

1) The easiest way is that we translate this text on our custom module or theme:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy this file to your theme folder (app/design/frontend/***Vendor***/***TemplateName***/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/coupon.phtml), then edit it as you like.

Rebuild the project
`bin/magento set:up && bin/magento s:d:c && bin/magento s:s:d -f && bin/magento c:f`

If you need to change only the text, then I do not recommend this method. It is better to use the manuals from the previous answer.